# Clash between development and production NuGet config files

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package, cicd, nuget-package-restore

My .net project is built locally by me during development, and remotely by my ci/cd server.

The project has **project-level config** in `myproject/nuget.config`. It is used by my ci/cd server, which provides some environment variables:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="custom" value="https://example.com/api/nuget/index.json" />
  </packageSources>

  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <custom>
      <!-- env vars provided by pipeline -->
      <add key="Username" value="%USERNAME%" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="%API_KEY%" />
    </custom>
  </packageSourceCredentials>

  <packageSourceMapping>
    <!-- get other packages from nuget server -->
    <packageSource key="nuget.org">
      <package pattern="*" />
    </packageSource>
    <!-- get own packages from private server -->
    <packageSource key="custom">
      <package pattern="MyOrg.*" />
    </packageSource>
  </packageSourceMapping>

</configuration>
```

My local machine has **user-level config** in `~/.nuget/Nuget/Nuget.Config`, which is the same, except for different credentials:

```xml
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <custom>
      <add key="Username" value="my_username" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="my_personal_api_key" />
    </custom>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
```

That works in the ci/cd server, i.e. in production.

But locally (i.e. in development), I get 401/Unauthorized errors when running `dotnet restore` (etc.) - because *the project-level config (which requires extra env vars) overwrites the user-level config*. (I have many other repos with the same issue, so I don't want to export env vars or add stuff to my .bashrc: it's messy, I don't want to do that.)

This seems to be the opposite to how it's typically done, where there is some "default" checked into source control, and it can be customised during development (with overriding config files) and production (with config files or env vars).

How do I do this?

(Cross-posted to [repo](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/discussions/12824).)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like that the '--configfile' switch of the 'dotnet restore' command could be of help. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore#options. You could invoke then

```
dotnet restore --configfile ~/.nuget/Nuget/Nuget.Config
```

Comment: That would work in many cases, but it would be important to duplicate all the config into the user config file, and remember that it would already contain config for other projects too; it'll get messy. I prefer to use the project config and rely on nuget's "merging" ability to merge the user config, rather than replace it. Also it's a bit of a pain to type that extra stuff every time. Nonetheless it's a good workaround for many people, thanks and +1!